# SQLite read the base from Assets after clearing the cache

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a Sqlite database that I read from the Assets file. That was the question of how to get around one moment. Everything works well, but if you go into settings -> application -> and clear the cache and data, databases, etc., then the application throws a SQLiteException no such table: bus_end (code 1): while compiling: SELECT * FROM because the base is overwritten .

Through the file manager, I see that the database exists, but it becomes just empty, which is logical. If you slip a kick through the manager, the new file all works further ... That is, I understand that the user can clear the cache and then everything will fall. Question How to solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private static String DB_NAME = "app_database.db";

private final Context myContext;

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;

}

/**
 *
 * Создает пустую базу данных в системе и переписывает ее с помощью собственной базы данных.
 */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (!dbExist)
        this.getWritableDatabase();//Создает и/или открывает базу данных
        if (myDataBase.isOpen()){
            myDataBase.close();
        }
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error(e + "Error copying database");

    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 *
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    try {
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        //database does't exist yet
    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException { //Откройте локальный db в качестве входного потока
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME); //Путь к только что созданному пустому db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; //Откройте пустой бит в качестве выходного потока
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    //передавать байты из входного файла в выходной файл
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    //Закрыть потоки
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DB_PATH;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}


//  ПОЛУЧИТЬ
public Cursor getAllData(String table_name) {
    myDataBase = getReadableDatabase();
    return myDataBase.query(table_name, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }



@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
```

And FRAGMENT

```
private void retrieve() {
listStationItemList.clear();
try {
    db.createDataBase();
    db.openDataBase();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//RETRIEVE
Cursor cursor = db.getAllData(TABLE_BUS);
//LOOP AND ADD TO ARRAYLIST
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    long _id = cursor.getLong(0);
    String name = cursor.getString(1);
    String details = cursor.getString(2);

    ItemListStation p = new ItemListStation(name, details);
    listStationItemList.add(p);
}
//CHECK IF ARRAYLIST ISNT EMPTY
if (!(listStationItemList.size() < 1)) {
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
db.close();
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you have a number of issues with the create/copy process;

- The **myDataBase** variable would be null.
- The DB_PATH variable is set to "", thus the copy fails due to being read-only, with an exception in the log similar to (note 2nd line, also note changed code to not catch such an exception and ignore it, thus the table not found because the new DB is empty not overwritten)

:-

```
2018-12-02 02:50:25.525 5780-5780/so53569158.so53569158fragmentlistview D/DBOUTFILE: Outfilename (the database file to be written to) is set to app_database.db
2018-12-02 02:50:25.525 5780-5780/so53569158.so53569158fragmentlistview D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2018-12-02 02:50:25.527 5780-5780/so53569158.so53569158fragmentlistview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: so53569158.so53569158fragmentlistview, PID: 5780
    java.lang.Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: app_database.db (Read-only file system)Error copying database
        at so53569158.so53569158fragmentlistview.DatabaseHelper.createDatabaseAlt(DatabaseHelper.java:59)
        at so53569158.so53569158fragmentlistview.DatabaseHelper.<init>(DatabaseHelper.java:29)
        at so53569158.so53569158fragmentlistview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

The following is a suggested way, that doesn't open the database but instead checks that the database file exists.

If it doesn't then it also check for the existence of the parent directory and creates it if it doesn't exist.

- The directory doesn't exist when no databases have been created.
- I believe the use of `checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);` was to overcome the directory not existing and can be problematic.
- There is potential flaw with just checking the file, in that there is the potential for it to not be a database file (a further check can be made by opening it a check the first 16 bytes which must conform the the SQLite Header data).

Anyway here's the code that's working

- Note the use of the RecyclerView and the ArrayList that sources it has been commented out so I didn't have to create code that was unnecessary for finding a solution.
- Note that some commented out code, was commented out, as it was replaced by alternative code or an alternative methodology.

#### 1. The Fragment code (MainFragment was used) :-

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

```
DatabaseHelper db;
String TABLE_BUS = "bus_end";


public static MainFragment newInstance() {
    return new MainFragment();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mis_entradas_local, container, false);
    db = new DatabaseHelper(getContext()); //<<<<<<<<<< Assumed you had this
    retrieve();                            //<<<<<<<<<< Assumed you had this
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

private void retrieve() {

    //listStationItemList.clear(); // Commented out for convenience

    /**
     *  Block commeneted out NOT NEEDED WITH NEW METHODOLOGY
      */
    /*
    try {
        db.createDataBase();
        db.openDataBase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    */

    //RETRIEVE
    Cursor cursor = db.getAllData(TABLE_BUS);
    //LOOP AND ADD TO ARRAYLIST
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        long _id = cursor.getLong(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        String details = cursor.getString(2);

        //ItemListStation p = new ItemListStation(name, details); //<<<<<<<<<< Commented out for convenience
        //listStationItemList.add(p); //<<<<<<<<<< Commented out for convenience
    }
    /**
     * Block below commented out for convenience
     */
    /*
    //CHECK IF ARRAYLIST ISNT EMPTY
    if (!(listStationItemList.size() < 1)) {
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    */
    db.close();
}
```

}

- Note it doesn't directly try call **createDatabase** and then **openDatabase**, this is done when the **DatabaseHelper** is constructed. Hence why the block of code has been commented out.

#### 2. DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private static String DB_NAME = "app_database.db";

    private final Context myContext;

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        createDatabaseAlt();
        myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    /**
     * NOTE NOT USED SEE createDatabaseAlt below (it's replacment)
     * Создает пустую базу данных в системе и переписывает ее с помощью собственной базы данных.
     */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getWritableDatabase(); //<<<<<<<<<< myDatabase will be null
            myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();//Создает и/или открывает базу данных
        }
        if (myDataBase.isOpen()){
            myDataBase.close();
        }
        try {
            copyDataBase(); //<<<<<<<<<< Copy fails due to app_database.db (Read-only file system)Error copying database
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error(e + "Error copying database");
        }
    }

    // Alternative Create Database
    public void createDatabaseAlt() {
        if (!checkDB()) {
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error(e + "Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     *
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        try {
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            //database does't exist yet
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null;
    }

    // Alternative Check that doesn't open the database to create the directory
    private boolean checkDB() {
        File db = new File(myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath());
        if (db.exists()) return true;
        File dbdir = new File(db.getParent());
        if (!dbdir.exists()) {
            dbdir.mkdirs();
        }
        return false;
    }


    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException { //Откройте локальный db в качестве входного потока
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME); //Путь к только что созданному пустому db

        //String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; //Откройте пустой бит в качестве выходного потока
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath());
        //передавать байты из входного файла в выходной файл
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        //Закрыть потоки
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    /**
     * Not used NOTE this open database as read-only and thus was the cause of one of the issues
     */
    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }


    //  ПОЛУЧИТЬ
    public Cursor getAllData(String table_name) {
        myDataBase = getReadableDatabase();
        return myDataBase.query(table_name, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }



    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

- Note old/redundant code has been left in and commented where necessary
- Please refer to/read the comments

Comment: Great, its work. **Thank you**.      I only need to tell those who will use this code that I had to change the path to the data :     `String outFileName = DB_PATH = myContext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/" + DB_NAME;`

Comment: One question that remained. How to call the Upgrade method correctly

Comment: You don't typically call onUpgrade, rather you get it to be called by increasing the Database version (actually it's the user_version in Sqlite where the value is stored). So in you code if you change DB_VERSION to 2 then onUpgarde will be called (once) (user_version will then be set to 2 in the actual data). If you change DB_VERSION to 3  (or any higher value) it will be called. Warning if you reduce the DB_VERSION an attempt will be made to call onDowngrade, which will crash unless it is overridden.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved in two ways :

> 1. coping database file to a directory in sdcard space that android setting cannot modify or access. by doing this method you should manage your database and system cannot have any change in your system.
> 2. the second way is to define an activity in manifest file to manage application data and by doing this , in setting for clearing data they will go to an activity in your application and you could manage your data in there. for this , first create an activity and define it in Manifest file like below :
>
>    > ```
>    >  <application
>    >   android:manageSpaceActivity="your activity" />
>    > ```

I recommend to use the second method.